# I require some help with traceping

Tags: ping

Does anyone have an idea what Traceping is and where I can find good info about it? Googled for it but could not find some.

Is there anywhere I could find out how to use traceping on Ubuntu? I tried to look for the package but could not find it anywhere.

Comment: I haven't seen that term before, but it could be a reference to the `ping -R` **record route** functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The only reference to "Traceping" I could find was [this one](http://androidforums.com/application-announcements/479397-tools-traceping-traceroute-ping.html), which refers to an android app. Basically, it performs a `traceroute` to discover all the hops between your location and the target IP, then continuously pings each host to provide you with more information about the quality of the connection.

If you didn't understand a word of what I just said, you probably don't need the tool.

Judging by its description, if you want similar functionality on a full linux system, your best bet is [MTR](http://www.bitwizard.nl/mtr/), which is included in pretty much every distribution worth the name that isn't actively going for absolutely minimal disk space footprint.

Answer (score 0):

I think you refer with "Trace-ping" to "traceroute" which print the route packets take to network host , this will help you troubleshooting networking issues and packet loss